# Show that $\exists \epsilon$ such that $f_{\epsilon}:=x+\epsilon g(x)$ is one-to-one where $g$ has bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Consider a differentiable function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with bounded derivative $g'$, i.e. $\exists M>0$ such that $|g'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the function $f_{\epsilon}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$f_{\epsilon}:=x+\epsilon g(x),$$
is one-to-one.

My workings so far: Because $|g'(x)|$ is bounded by $M$ on the entire real line, we know that 
$$f_{\epsilon}'(x)=1+\epsilon g'(x)$$
And thus:
$$1-\epsilon M \leq f_{\epsilon}'(x) \leq 1+\epsilon M$$
If we choose $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2M}$ (which is always possible as $M>0$) then
$$\frac{1}{2} \leq f'_{\epsilon}(x) \leq \frac{3}{2}$$
Therefore $f$ is increasing on the entire real line.

Now comes my problem, I want to use the fact that $f_{\epsilon}$ is monotonically increasing to show that it is one-to-one. To that end, let's argue by contradiction. Suppose $f_{\epsilon}$ is not one-to-one and therefore $\exists x_1,x_2$ such that $f_{\epsilon}(x_1)=f_{\epsilon}(x_2)$ where $x_1 \neq x_2$. Without loss of generality, let's assume $x_1<x_2$.

However, as $f_{\epsilon}$ is increasing we know that $f_{\epsilon}$ satisfies the strict inequality 
$$f_{\epsilon}(x_1) < f_{\epsilon}(x_2)$$
which contradicts our assumption. Therefore $f_{\epsilon}$ is one-to-one.

Is this enough to show $f_{\epsilon}$ is one-to-one? Thanks

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well I showed that $x_1 \neq x_2$ implies $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$, but dont I need to also show the converse? namely that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$?

Comment: This is just the contrapositive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is all correct. If $g$ is also bounded you could prove that such $f_\epsilon$ is a bijection.

Comment: Very late response. Thank you, in hind sight, I am quite sure I was thinking of bijections instead of injections as your remark suggests.